# Iphone App Rejected Ipv6 Incompatibility

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, networking, ipv6

My application has been rejected twice for Incompatibility over Ipv6 network.

This question has been asked several times. Most of the solutions suggested to avoid using third party api for http request and do not hard code ipaddress. I have not done neither.

However does my server have to be ipv6 compatible or is there something wrong with my http request.

So I tested my server https://services.fingrowthbank.com/ on this website http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php for Ipv6 readiness testing. It shows as incompatible. Could this be a reason for the rejection?

Code for http request

```
let nsUrlObject: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlAndMethod)!
let nsMutableUrlRequestObj: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: nsUrlObject, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: nstime_out_intervalObj)

nsMutableUrlRequestObj.HTTPMethod = “POST"
let bodyData = httpBodyStr
nsMutableUrlRequestObj.HTTPBody =  bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

nsMutableUrlRequestObj.setValue(httpHeaderStr, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(nsMutableUrlRequestObj, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
{
  (response, data, error) in

   if response == nil
   {
      print(error)
      alert.view.removeFromSuperview()
      Imps_http_client.showAlertView("Could not connect to the server")
    }else{

    }

 }
```

Comment: YES, the app can't be used in IPv6 connectivity, the url is problem check [this](http://teamarin.net/2014/10/30/8-steps-get-site-ready-ipv6/)

Comment: earliar it allow ipv4 but now its mandatory to support all your webservicesin ipv6 thats the actual reason , last time i uploaded an app , i got a warning regarding this so better to switch all your webserivce into ipv6 compliance

Comment: You're on a wild goose chase. Instead of worrying about your server supporting IPv6, you need to be worrying about the bug in your application that Apple told you about...but which you didn't tell us about.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your code. The problem is your server side.

As per https://services.fingrowthbank.com/ your server is not compatibility with IPV6. Because I found that you are using old security encryption i.e, Obsolete Cipher suite .

I under lined inside the image.

I tested with sample server. **Example:** Apple. This apple is using **modern cipher suite**

[image: Apple server]

The problem with your server there is a chance of **security attack number 13**. This is the reason the apple is rejected your app. Update your app with late security.

**Solution:** Just update your server to **modern cipher suite**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This url is perfectly fine  as far as your are using domain name for sending request to server.
[according to apple  If you’re writing a client-side app using high-level networking APIs such as NSURLSession and the CFNetwork frameworks and you connect by name, you should not need to change anything for your app to work with IPv6 addresses. If you aren’t connecting by name, you probably should be.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1)

check your code or any third party components you are using and make sure your are not sending any request with IP address instead of domain name. Specifically, Check [Reacahbility](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_m.html) code. If you are using it, don't use function  `reachabilityWithAddress` , use `reachabilityWithHostName`  instead. `reachabilityForInternetConnection` is also using `reachabilityWithAddress` - If you are using this, then edit it.

At last, you  can validate your app for ipv6 by creating ipv6 network with mac and testing app with that network.

Comment: I have not used third party api for http request. There is no problem with my Reachabilty code as well. Does just having a domain name satisfy that the application will work on ipv6 network.

Comment: Yes, according to this link, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1 it satisfy. Why don't you create test ipv6 network and check.

Comment: I have done that. My Question is Does my server accept request coming from an ipv6 network.